# String concatenation not working, or is it a bug

Tags: java, string

I have written some code and used a string that I concatentated using the += (as I only do it a couple of times.

Later on I used another string and used the concat() function. and the concatenation didn't work.

So I wrote a little method in Junit (with eclipse)...

```
@Test
public void StingConcatTest(){

    String str = "";

    str += "hello ";
    str += " and goodbye";

    String conc="";
    conc.concat("hello ");
    conc.concat(" and goodbye");
    System.out.println("str is: " + str + "\nconc is: "+ conc);
```

The output is...

```
str is: hello  and goodbye
conc is:
```

So either I'm going mad, I'm doing something wrong (most likely), there is an issue in JUNIT, or there is a problem with my JRE / eclipse or something.

Note that stringbuilders are working fine.

David.

Comment: Google must be broken again. ;)

Comment: @peter I did search google, and no responses said had a good response like the one from nambari below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, we see this question at least couple of times a day.

`Strings` are `immutable`, so all operations on String results in new `String`.

`conc= conc.concat("hello ");` you need to reassign result to string again

Comment: Ok I feel stupid. End of the day and not enough refreshments.

Answer (score 3):

You have to try with:

```
String conc="";
conc = conc.concat("hello ");
conc = conc.concat(" and goodbye");
System.out.println("str is: " + str + "\nconc is: "+ conc);
```

For sake of optimization you can write:

```
String conc="";
conc = conc.concat("hello ").concat(" and goodbye");
System.out.println("str is: " + str + "\nconc is: "+ conc);
```

Comment: String is ALWAYS constant. When you use these methods (like concat()) you just create a NEW object String.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on concatenating multiple Strings you could also use StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("hello");
builder.append(" blabla");
builder.append(" and goodbye");
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

concat returns a String. It doesn't update the original String.

Answer (score 0):

concat() returns the concatenated string.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String s = "foo";

    String x = s.concat("bar");

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.concat doesn't change the string it is called on - it returns a new string which is the string and the argument concatenated together.

By the way: string concatenation using concat or += is not very performant. You should use the class [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.